# Daily Reminder Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, custom-list, email, reminder

i have a small workflow requirement that seems complex to me.

**Requirement**
I have a custom list where in i want to send daily reminder mails to each user whose list item status is pending.

Now what i want the workflow to do is to run every day at 9:00 A.M and send a auto mail to users whose activity have status **Pending**.

Then, to send another reminder mail at 4:00 P.M the same day for the activites whose status is **Pending**.

Now, at 6:00 P.M, i want the auto mail to trigger for those activities whose status is **Pending** and send a mail to users manager.(Like an escalation mail).

if the activity status has been set to **completed** by user, the auto mail sends a notification to usres manager saying the activity has been completed .

**Note: i want the workflow to run every day and to check for items which are pending. 

Also, i want a bulk email for all those activity to users which are pending and not a single email as this would make user annoyed.**

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic requirement and here is to give you generic idea on how to implement. 
Assuming you are on SharePoint online.

There are 2 options
Option 1. Create Microsoft flow with re-occurrence every day on timing like 9 AM, 4 PM and 6 PM, you need to implemented all your custom logic in flow to send on basis of your conditions like status is pending, completed. Basically below would be logic

1. Query List based on filter where status is pending
   If it is 9 AM, send mail to user with a email template
   If it is 4 PM, send mail to user with a separate email content 
   if it is 6 PM, send mail to manager for escalation.
2. Query list based on filter where status is completed
   If it is 6 PM, send mail to manager that activity is completed.

You should also have some extra columns to identify if reminders being send like
9 AM, 4 PM, 6 PM etc...

Reference link to create MS flow to send mails
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community-Blog/Creating-a-List-Reminder-Flow/ba-p/130025

Option 2 - is to create a powershell script or .NET console application using SP Online CSOM and have same logic as above. Schedule this script or .NET application with windows scheduler to run at your specific interval time.

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!!